# ArgumentError: wrong # of arguments(0 for 1) Rails Unit Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

the error says "ArgumentError: wrong # of arguments(0 for 1)" for:

```
def test_auth
  #check that we can login we a valid Usuario
  assert_equal  @bob, Usuario.autenticar("bob", "test")
end
```

But, autenticar DOES take 2 arguments:

```
def self.autenticar(usuario, clave)
  u=find(:first, :conditions=>["usuario = ?", usuario])
  return nil if u.nil?
  return u if Usuario.encrypt(clave, u.salt)==u.clave
  nil
end
```

Whats happening?

Comment: Have you checked which line is causing the error? *0 for 1* means that 1 argument was expected but 0 were given so it's unlikely to be the call to `autenticar`.

Comment: apparently the error happens on this line:  return u if Usuario.encrypt(clave, u.salt)==u.clave

Comment: It sounds like either `u.salt` or `u.clave` is actually a function which expects at least one parameter.

Comment: Yep, that was right.... I had:
  def clave(clave)
    @clave=clave
    self.salt = Usuario.random_string(10) if !self.salt?
    self.clave_enc = Usuario.encrypt(clave, self.salt)
  end

Comment: tiiin4, can you please add your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer so the question gets marked as answered? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments section, the method `clave` within `autenticar` expected an argument and didn't get one.